# Can a US citizen living abroad with a permanent US address use that address to open a portfolio account?

Tags: united-states, international

I am a US citizen living in Germany and I want to open a portfolio account in the US. I use my sister's US address as my mailing address. Can this also serve as my permanent US address (which, I'm told, is required to open the account)?

Comment: Which address(es) do you use to file your US taxes? I assume the portfolio account you're looking to open is a brokerage and/or bank account, right?

Comment: I think this is going to revolve around whether you are 'temporarily' living abroad or whether you have moved abroad permanently.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that you can. Being a US citizen, you're taxed on your earnings, so from the US-bank perspective the address is just a place to send the mail to. However, if you're also a German/EU taxpayer - you should check their laws and regulations wrt reporting of gains and tax payment.

From US-tax perspective it will be **better** for you to keep your investments in the US. Foreign investments are taxed more aggressively and at higher rates by the US.